# sqlite3: I want to select rows based on a list of IDs from a different table

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got two tables, routes and users. Each route has a integer id, and each user has a comma separated list of routes they have access to. I'm attempting to select those rows from the routes table where their ids are in the list of ids in the user row.

The query (at least how I think it should be formed) I'm attempting to use is something like

```
select *
from routes
where id in (select allowed_ids
             from users
             where username = 'sameple');
```

The route table is formatted as

```
id, name
0, 'test name'
2, 'test name'
3, 'test name'
```

The user table is formatted as

```
id, name, username, password, allowed_ids
0, 'name', 'uname', 'md5pw', '0, 3'
```

The issue is, this doesn't work. Is there a better way or doing this?

I'm quite new to SQL, so any help is greately appreciated!

Comment: What is your question? What you are using is sub-query which a valid option to get results from one table based on values from other table.

Comment: You will find it useful to use a join here.

Comment: @squiguy Okay, how so?

Comment: `select * from routes join users on id = allowed_ids where username = 'sample'`.  See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) for more information on joins.

Comment: So that will work with comma separated values in the users.allowed_ids field?

Comment: @JonBloom Is `users.allowed_ids` an array or comma separated text?

Comment: Currently comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a third table where the userID and routeID is saved.

```
UserRoutes
PrimaryKey->ID
ForeignKey->UserID
ForeignKey->RoutesKey

Users
PrimaryKey->ID

Routes
PrimaryKey->ID
```

So you can

```
SELECT * FROM UserRoutes, Routes WHERE UserRoutes.UserID = x;
```

That think this the standard way in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, but something like this might:

```
select r.*
from routes r
where exists (select 1
              from users u
              where username = 'sameple' and
                    ', '||u.allowed_ids||', ' like '%, '||id||', %'
             );
```

You can also express this as a `join`, but this keeps the spirit of your attempt.

Storing lists of things in comma separate text columns is a *bad* idea.  You should have a separate table with one row per user and allowed_id.

Comment: What was the problem?